# Calling setValuesForKeys fails in my Swift 4 code

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, swift4, nskeyvaluecoding

I'm having this problem, im trying to retrieve data from the firebase database, but it's saying the profilepic isn't a key, but it is. This is the object class.

```
class User: NSObject {
    var firstname: String?
    var lastname: String?
    var username: String?
    var profilepic: String?
}
```

and this is me trying to retrieve

```
func getusers(){
        ref.child("Friends").child(currentuser!).observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in
            print(snapshot)
            if let dic = snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject]{
                let user = User()
                user.setValuesForKeys(dic)
                print(user.firstname, user.lastname)

                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.tableview.reloadData()
                }}
        }) { (error) in
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }

    }
```

and the crash is here `user.setValuesForKeys(dic)`.

Anyone has any idea why isn't working?

Comment: are you sure profilepic is a string?

Comment: Yes. Its a url absolute string

Comment: "profilepic" : url.absoluteString

Comment: If you inspect `dic` before `setValuesForKeys`, what does the dictionary look like?

Comment: I think I found the problem, but idk how to solve it. It's crashing, because my User is returning nil, so it's returning nothing, i have to make snapshot throw the values into User class then retrieve to the dictionary with the actual values.

Comment: but the main crash it says profilepic is not  key value

Comment: the snapshot is working, is retrieving all the users, but my thing isn't throwing the retrieve values to my User class for some reason

Comment: Don't force unwrap values, that should fix 95% of mistakes you are doing.

Comment: can you please show the Dict output you getting from server as I think something is wrong with the method you had written to get data in user keys

Comment: I got it guys, thank you very much !

Answer (score 3):

Try this instead:

```
@objcMembers
class User: NSObject {
    ...
}
```

The `setValuesForKeys` API is implemented by the Foundation framework and requires Objective-C compatibility.

The rules for exposing Swift code to Objective-C have changed considerably in Swift 4. Please [check the evolution proposal](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0160-objc-inference.md) for further information.

**User class design**. If any of the four properties can be missing from Firebase than your class design might be a good fit. Otherwise, consider declaring the fixed properties as non-optional and creating an initializer instead.

Answer (score 1):

Change your User declaration to this:

```
class User: NSObject {
    @objc var firstname: String?
    @objc var lastname: String?
    @objc var username: String?
    @objc var profilepic: String?
}
```

In Swift 4, Objective-C cannot see your instance properties unless you expose them explicitly.